# Factory Girl rspec issue: has_many through factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, factory-bot

I am having an issue regarding Factory Girl in Rails. I currently have pundit setup  am trying to test my user policies yet the factory does not seem to work when in rspec.

Inside the rails console, I can load up the console and type:

```
    user=FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
    r=user.roles
```

This works correctly creates a user and the correct associations between a user and a role. However, when the factory is used in rspec- A user is created but not the associated assignment. (I discovered this by using 'pp' inside the specific tests.)

I do not need to create a role, since the roles are set so I am looking them up.

Any ideas?

## Models

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :assignments, dependent: :destroy
     has_many :roles, through: :assignments, dependent: :destroy

      def has_role?(roles)
        roles.each do |role|
          if self.roles.include? role
            return true
          end
        end

        false
      end

    class Role < ApplicationRecord
      # Associations
      has_many :assignments
      has_many :users, through: :assignments

    class Assignment < ApplicationRecord
      # Associations
      belongs_to :user
      belongs_to :role
```

## Factories

```
    FactoryGirl.define do
      factory :user do
        first_name  {Faker::Name.first_name}
        last_name   {Faker::Name.last_name}
        email       {Faker::Internet.email}
        password    {Faker::Internet.password(8)}

          factory :admin_user do
                after(:create) do |user|
                Assignment.create(user: user , role: Role.find_by(label:'System Admin') )
            end
          end

      end
    end
```

## Tests

### User Policy Test

```
    describe UserPolicy do
      subject { UserPolicy }

       let (:current_user) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user}
       let (:other_user) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :user }
       let (:admin) { FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :admin_user}


      permissions :index? do
        it "denies access if not an admin" do
          expect(UserPolicy).not_to permit(current_user)
        end
        it "allows access for an admin" do
          expect(UserPolicy).to permit(admin)
        end
      end
    end
```

### Other Test With same Issue

```
    feature 'User index page', :devise do

      after(:each) do
        Warden.test_reset!
      end

      scenario 'user sees own email address' do
        user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user)
        expect(user.has_role?(Role.where(label: 'System Admin'))).to eq true
        login_as(user, scope: :user)
        visit users_path
        expect(page).to have_content user.email
      end

    end
```

This test fails since the user has no role assigned.

## Controller

```
    class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
      def create
        @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
        if @assignment.save
          redirect_to users_path(), :notice => "Role Added"
        else
          flash[:alert]="Unable to Add Role"
        end
      end
```

Comment: In your `after(:create)` block, you look for a role.  But have you verified that the role exists? `find_by` will pass nil and not throw an error if a record isn't found.  It's equivalent to `where(<criteria>).first`

Comment: Also, just as a heads up, look into `byebug` for stuff like this.  If you've never used it, it's a fantastic debugging tool

Comment: got it sorted! Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you posted what you got sorted out as the answer so that it can serve future users. Remember, this is not just for you, the purpose of posting questions is also to help others. Additionally, I was going to suggest you need to set up each user in your factory as a separate block, you seem to have all your :user and :admin_user in the same do block.